# How to use the local devenv deploy command with git-bash and visual studio 17?

Tags: bash, visual-studio, windows-10

In my work we have 2 projects, one needs to be deployed either locally if we are in dev, or online on Azure. I would like to create a script that will allow publishing this project locally using the devenv command with option /Deploy as in the MSDN doc, I do not need to do it for the online deployment. It's just to save time every day in my development
I do not understand why with the command line do not work...
Thanks for your help!
(Visual Studio 2017, git-bash, c#)

the command line :

- devenv (path to devenv.exe)
- solution (path to .sln)
- project (path to csproj to deploy)

  $devenv $solution /Deploy Debug /Project $project  /ProjectConfig Debug /Out returnFile

i have something in return :

```
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 1: $'\357\273\277': command not found
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 2: Microsoft: command not found
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 4: VisualStudioVersion: command not found
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 5: MinimumVisualStudioVersion: command not found
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `"{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}"'
D:/Solutions/Core/Core.sln: line 6: `Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Seedwork", "Seedwork", "{EBE07DC1-8E03-4235-995F-57AC26337525}"'
```

Comment: What do you mean with "with the command line i have nothing in Git bash"?

Comment: I use the command line type with the option /T, and the only thing i have it's the readme whitch explain the command and the different options

Comment: This is only a guess but you do know that git-bash and cmd.exe use completely different path styles right?  For instance running `C:\windows\notepad.exe` from git-bash produces ***bash: c:windowsnotepad.exe: command not found***

Comment: i edit my post to give precision